# Matching special characters in with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with lines as below. My goals is to mask the value of fields such as Name, DOB, Email Address, Mailing Address, Residential Address, Phone Number, Other Phone Number with **. The tricky part is, that there might not be a predictable length of the text before the next field starts. For example, where the City ends and the State starts.. so maybe use * to know the end point? I am using a .sed file and running it against this log file. The "|" are all part of the file as well. It is basically a screen outputted into a log file

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------
    | XXX XX Requested function key not allocated.                                  |
    |     ***** System *****                                                         |
    |                           - Maintain  -              11:55 AM                  |
    | < 1 more  P                                                           3 more > |
    | *Action (A,D,M): _                                                                      |
    |  Office Number: 14                                                             |
    | Case ID:    XXXXXXXXX    Email Address: ___________________________________    |
    | Name: TWENTYFIFTEE MAYSEVEN          DOB: 11111950  *Correspondence Lang: _    |
    |                            Street One                    Street Two            |
    | Mailing Address....: 7 MAY____________________    _________________________    |
    | City...............: DALLAS_________ *State: TX Zip Code: 75062 - ____         |
    |                                                                                |
    | Residential Address: 7 MAY____________________    _________________________    |
    | City...............: DALLAS_________ *State: TX Zip Code: 75062 - ____         |
    | Phone Number...:( ___ ) ___ - ____    Other Phone Number:( ___ ) ___ - ____    |
    | Authorized Rep                     Last      TTL   First   MI                  |
    |                              Name........: ____________ ___ _________ _        |
    | Authorized Representative Phone Number: ( ___ ) ___ - ____                     |
    | Last Updt Dttm......: 05/07/2015 11:55:01 AM   Last Update User: JU14          |
    |                         XXXXXX               XXXXXX                            |
    |                                                                                |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: is structure always the same (same field order and place) ? when you specify *there might not be a predictable length of the text*, is it mulmtiline possible, just the next field starting after the end of content or cotent length is unknow and feeded with *space* until next field name (that is at the same place in *screen*) ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu multiline is not possible. It's just a matter of finding the appropriate tag and replacing the value. The option suggested by Martin Konecny below is a feasible one, but for whatever reason, I am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's case by case option using delimiters

```
for Balise in '| Name: <-> DOB:' ' DOB: <->   |' ' Email Address: <->   |' 
 do
   sed ":cycle
      s/\(${Balise%<->*}[*]*\)[^*]\(.*${Balise#*<->}\)/\1*\2/
      t cycle" YourFile > TempFile
   mv TempFile YourFile
 done
```

- use 2 delimiters per change. Each change delimiters is define in the `for in` loop entry via a string composed of 1st delimiter followed by `<->` and end delimiter.

  - I add 3 samples in this code
  - you can use other sequence of character as separator between delimiter but adapt the sed part in consequence (in fact the `<->` in `${Balise...}`
- sed will recursively change character between the 2 delimiters by `*`
- you can use `-i` option with GNU sed in place of a temporary file used here for any version

Answer (score 1):

> so maybe use * to know the end point?

I'm not sure if this is a good approach. Doesn't seem like all fields are followed by a `*`, and this doesn't cover the case where the field's value has a `*` in it.

Assuming you can just replace the entire field with `*` characters, I would break this into multiple `sed` commands (one for each field you want to replace).

It will also require a bit of manual work; here we replace 30 characters of almost any type `.` with 30 `*` characters since that is how many characters the "name" value field has.

```
name_len=30
sed -r "s/(Name: ).{,$name_len}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..$name_len})/g"
```

The effect of this on on your 9th line is

```
| Name: ****************************** DOB: 11111950  *Correspondence Lang: _    |
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin Konecny. I will give this a shot and keep you posted

Comment: I get the following error:
    ` sed: 1: test.sed: extra characters at the end of n command`

Comment: Im running this on a mac. So I tried it with the -i option and am getting "unterminated substitute pattern"

Comment: What's the output if you do `cat filename | sed -r "s/(Name: ).{,$name_len}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..$name_len})/g"`?

Comment: I get "sed: illegal option -- r"

Comment: I see. On OS X, you will need to replace the `-r` option with `-E` instead.

Comment: I did that as well and nothing is replaced.. I have a .sed file where in I have your commands placed. Then when I run it as "sed -E -f screenLogMasking.sed sL.txt >> 1.txt" , I get "sed: 1: screenLogMasking.sed: extra characters at the end of n command"

Comment: The screenLogMasking.sed file looks like this (on separate lines):
`code`
    name_len=30
    s/(Name: ).{,$name_len}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..$name_len})/g
 `code`

Comment: ok let's take it one step at a time. Does it work if you paste those commands into the shell. We can get it working for the sed file next.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when pasted in the shell

Comment: `Scripts$ name_len=30`
`Scripts$ cat sL.txt | sed -E "s/(Name: ).{,$name_len}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..$name_len})/g" >> test.out`

No error is thrown but nothing is replaced in the file.

Comment: You are saying that `test.out` is the same as `sL.txt` after running the command?

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: It looks like the variable assignment on MacOsx should be different? Im trying to figure out what that should be.

Comment: Even hardcoding the value replaces nothing in the file `cat sL.txt | sed -E "s/(\| Name: ).{,30}/\1$(printf '*%.0s '{1..30})/g" >> test.out`

Comment: I met some headway. It looks like on MacOSX, it doesnt like the ,30. So there fore running the above command as `cat sL.txt | | sed -E "s/(Name: ).{30}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..30})/g"` seems to do the substitution. Now, to get it work within the sed file :)

Comment: If you paste everything in between the double quotes, it should work: `s/(Name: ).{30}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..30})/g`. Good job debugging it on OS X

Comment: for some reason when adding this to the sed file the $printf is not being evaulated.. so perhaps another quirk on MacOSX? This is what I have in the sed file `s/(Name: ).{30}/\1$(printf '*%.0s' {1..30})/g` . .what this is yielding is `Name:  $(printf '*%.0s' {1..30})`

Comment: no actually that's an oversight on my part - it's a bash shell command. You can either replace it with 30 `*` characters (not ideal) if you want to run it with a sed file - or why not simply create a shell script? You would paste the two lines as I originally posted + your modifications into this script.

Comment: That makes sense to put it in a shell script. Thank you again. I'll give this a shot and keep you posted